# How to Separate the XML File based on nodes in batch file , If Xml file has header that include line count too

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

IF XML has more than 1200 line "`<SpendDataLine>`" then create the separate file.
If 5000 Spend data lines then it should generate 5 files like

```
Spenddatafeed_yyyymmdd_1.xml
Spenddatafeed_yyyymmdd_2.xml
Spenddatafeed_yyyymmdd_3.xml
Spenddatafeed_yyyymmdd_4.xml
Spenddatafeed_yyyymmdd_5.xml
```

every file includes the Header node  `<SpendFeedHeader>` with every files Spend data lines count.

I have to achieve this from batch cmd / batch file how can we do that.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: Questions asking for a script when providing only a set of parameters are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please post your script to date and provide us with an explanation of what it does in relation to what was expected. See: [mcve]